# upload images using RESTAPI

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I am working with an app using Django Rest Framework.

**models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image_meta = models.ForeignKey('Image_Meta',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    image_path = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    version = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        field = ('id', 'image_path' , 'order' , 'version')
```

**views.py**

```
class ImageList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer

class ImageDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
```

**url patterns**

```
url(r'^image/$',views.ImageList.as_view(),name='image_list'),
url(r'^image/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.ImageDetail.as_view(),name='image_detail')
```

This is just a part of the whole system. **I want to upload images using the RESTAPI and then upload it to amazon s3 and from there get the url and store it in the *image_path* field of the model Image.** I have seen previous solutions for uploading files using REST ([like this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjW6qX13JzLAhXQcI4KHXjyAiIQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F3938569%2Fhow-do-i-upload-a-file-with-metadata-using-a-rest-web-service&usg=AFQjCNFcYQaJ8Yf9J07a42HCxtjifWa5jg&bvm=bv.115339255,d.c2E))but nothing worked for my case. Can someone suggest how can I do that?

Comment: You should just use `ImageField`. With this, actual image will be saved in S3 only and the field in DB will have path to the image which, in code, you can access using `image.url`.

Comment: @SaurabhGoyal Please elaborate how can I access image url?

Comment: But how can the image will get uploaded to s3...when I am trying it gets downloaded on the same project folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally have figured out how this can be done. I changed the image_path to ImageField as suggested by Saurabh Goyal. I used this code:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image_meta = models.ForeignKey('Image_Meta',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    image_path = models.ImageField(upload_to='images-data')
    order = models.IntegerField()
    version = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

N provided my amazon s3 bucket details as in the **local_settings.py** file as :

```
AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "Access_key_id"
AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "secret_access_key"
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "bucket_name"
```

and added this to **settings.py** :

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

and voila!! It worked. I hope this helps someone stuck at the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0):

We know that images/files are uploaded using [multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean). By Default DRF don't parse multipart data.

To make drf parse multipart data you have to tell DRP view to use [MultiPartParser](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser) parser.

```
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser
class ImageList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    ...
    ...     
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser)
    ...
```

I'll recommend to have a [imagefield](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#imagefield) in your serializer for image field, and process it there to upload to amazon and populate URLField